# Transparency of fixed header

Tags: css

I need to adjust the transparency of the fixed header of my website (which uses a background image) to be like this header: 
http://partypoker.com/download.html
My question is: which element in the header should be adjusted: the image or the header container? or both, and how?

My header: http://presentationtube.com/header_fixed.php
Backgrond image: http://presentationtube.com/images/templatemo_header_bg_65_ora.jpg

Template CSS: http://presentationtube.com/templatemo_style_fixed.css

Comment: You could make the image transparent (png) or add a nested element inside your header which contains the image and set the opacity through CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is replace background of your image for transparent. I've set this one for you for 60% opacity.

You have to replace the 166 line of code css to this:

```
background: url(images/templatemo_header_bg_65_ora.png) repeat-x;
```

And upload file to server.

//EDIT
It looks that you have to also remove background from your logo. Just replace file.[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank yoy Axwell, I did, but not working, here it is after update http://presentationtube.com

Comment: I've updated my post. Replace 166 line of code agin because you have to also remove the color.